# Real time Javascript filtering not working throws undefined

Tags: javascript

I want the code to return items from the JSON when i write something in the search bar (getting data from JSON tested and working).
The code is supposed to go to the JSON, read the line of the JSON (object) and compare with the keyword to see if it contains the keyword. If it contains it will display in `<li>` the item. It is always throwing "undefined".

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Users" id="filter_items"/>

<ul id="items-list">

</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var json = (function() {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'crossDomain': true,
            'method': "get",
            'url': "products.json",
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();


    // lets filters it
    ul = document.getElementById("items-list");
    input = document.getElementById('filter_items');

    var filterItems = function(event, json){
      keyword = input.value.toLowerCase();
      var li = "";

        for (var index in json)
        {
          for (var j in json[index])
            {
              var line = json[index][j];
              var filtered_items = line.title.filter(function(lin){
                    lin = lin.title.toLowerCase();
                   return lin.title.indexOf(keyword) > -1;
              });
            }
        }
        li += "<li>"+filtered_items+"</li>";
        ul.innerHTML = li;
    }


      input.addEventListener('keyup', filterItems);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON

```
{
    "items": [{
        "title": "Express"
    }, {
        "title": "Unexpress"
    }]
}
```

It is supposed to return items matching the keyword in real time.

**UPDATE**

JSON isn't passing as parameter into the function with event as parameter too. Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: The value of `line.title` is a string, and strings don't have a `.filter()` method.

Comment: What should i change?

Comment: Well I don't know because filtering a string doesn't make sense; maybe just a regex test?

Comment: JSON isn't passing as parameter into the function with event as parameter too. and that is why i get undefined: Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing an additional variable to the function when you trigger the event, so it's unclear why you'd expect `json` to be populated.

But you don't need it anyway - the content of JSON doesn't change every time the event happens, the data is always the same. Just download it when your page loads, and then add the event listener when it's finished downloading, and use the function without the additional parameter. `json` can be declared global so it'll be in scope.

I think the code might make more sense like this:

```
var json = null;
$.ajax({
    'global': false,
    'crossDomain': true,
    'method': "get",
    'url': "products.json",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data;
        input.addEventListener('keyup', filterItems);
    }
});

ul = document.getElementById("items-list");
input = document.getElementById('filter_items');

var filterItems = function(event){
  keyword = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var li = "";

  for (var index in json)
  {
    for (var j in json[index])
    {
      var line = json[index][j];
      var filtered_items = line.title.filter(function(lin){
        lin = lin.title.toLowerCase();
        return lin.title.indexOf(keyword) > -1;
      });
    }
  }
  li += "<li>"+filtered_items+"</li>";
  ul.innerHTML = li;
}
```

P.S. `'async': false` is deprecated due to the poor user experience it creates (locking up the main browser UI during requests). Some browsers will issue a console warning when you try to use it. But there should be no need for it. You should aim to use callbacks/promises correctly instead. I removed it in my example above, and instead (for reliability) we don't add the event listener to the input box until the JSON download has completed. Hopefully it isn't too big a file.

P.P.S. If you ever find yourself swapping the static JSON file for a server-side script to retrive product data from a database, it would be advisable to change your code so that the filtering of data happens on the server - usually it's a lot more efficient to filter using a SQL query and return only the data which is truly needed, than to download everything and then filter it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the filtering part should be changed.
Maybe to something like the following?

```js
    var json = { "items": [{"title": "Express"}, { "title": "Unexpress"}] };


    // lets filters it
    ul = document.getElementById("items-list");
    input = document.getElementById('filter_items');

    var filterItems = (event) => {
      keyword = input.value.toLowerCase();
      var li = "";


       var filtered_items = json.items.filter(function(lin){
                   return lin.title.toLowerCase() == keyword;
              });
       
       for ( var i in filtered_items ) {
        li += "<li>"+filtered_items[i].title+"</li>";
        }
        ul.innerHTML = li;
    }


      input.addEventListener('keyup', filterItems);
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Users" id="filter_items"/>

<ul id="items-list">

</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```